# Get Epoch Information for finished epochs

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api, epoch

My goal is to implement a function which gets epoch information of finished epochs from a node.
The input should be the epoch nr and the output should contain:

- First block
- First block timestamp
- Last block
- Last block timestamp

Similar to what i get when looking at the Epoch info on Solana-Explorer:
https://explorer.solana.com/epoch/417

I only found GetEpochInfo() so far, but here i only get information about the current epoch.
Is there a way to get this information by calling Rpc Methods on a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from RPC methods, you can:

- fetch the epoch schedule using `getEpochSchedule` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getepochschedule
- calculate the slots for your epoch or use the `EpochSchedule` class in JS https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/master/packages/library-legacy/src/epoch-schedule.ts
- fetch the block for the first and last slot using `getBlock` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getblock
- extract the timestamp from the block at the `"blockTime"` field

The explorer is open-source, so feel free to see how it's being done there! Here's the epoch details page https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/blob/master/src/pages/EpochDetailsPage.tsx